# How do I test a GEM with local GEM dependencies, $LOADED_FEATURES is not pointing my local GEMs

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a gem called `KBuilder::Watch` which uses a bunch of GEM's that I also developed.

The normal dependency management in `.gemspec` is as follows:

```rb
spec.add_dependency 'k_builder', '~> 0.0'
spec.add_dependency 'k_builder-dotnet', '~> 0.0'
spec.add_dependency 'k_builder-package_json', '~> 0.0'
spec.add_dependency 'k_builder-webpack5', '~> 0.0'
spec.add_dependency 'k_doc', '~> 0.0'
spec.add_dependency 'k_log', '~> 0.0'
spec.add_dependency 'k_util', '~> 0.0'
```

These GEMs have previously been installed into an ASDF environment via [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/profiles/klueless) and `bundle install`

I have overriden this using GemFile

```rb
gem 'k_builder'               , path: '../k_builder'
gem 'k_builder-package_json'  , path: '../k_builder-package_json'
gem 'k_builder-webpack5'      , path: '../k_builder-webpack5'
gem 'k_doc'                   , path: '../k_doc'
gem 'k_log'                   , path: '../k_log'
gem 'k_util'                  , path: '../k_util'
```

I am running k_builder-watch exe using

```sh
/Users/username/dev/kgems/k_builder-watch/exe/k_builder-watch
```

When I run the application and check what ruby files are loaded via the `$LOADED_FEATURES` array, all of the external dependency code in memory are coming from the installed GEMS path instead of local path.

```rb
my_gems = %w(handlebars-helpers k_builder k_builder-dotnet k_builder-watch k_builder-package_json k_builder-webpack5 k_doc k_log k_util)

loaded_files = $LOADED_FEATURES.select { |gem| my_gems.any? { |my_gem| gem.include?(my_gem) } }.sort

puts loaded_files
```

[image: Remote Dependencies]

### I've made progress towards a solution

I have just tested this same flow from a unit test in `k_builder-watch` GEM and all files in the `$LOADED_FEATURES` array are now pointing to my local dependencies, from this I have worked out that the issue is environmental.

```rb
RSpec.describe KBuilder::Watch::Watcher do
  let(:watch_path) { '/Users/davidcruwys/dev/kgems/k_builder-watch/.builders' }

  it {
    watcher = KBuilder::Watch::Watcher.new(watch_path)
    watcher.start
  }
end
```

```rb
my_gems = %w(handlebars-helpers k_builder k_builder-dotnet k_builder-watch k_builder-package_json k_builder-webpack5 k_doc k_log k_util)

loaded_files = $LOADED_FEATURES.select { |gem| my_gems.any? { |my_gem| gem.include?(my_gem) } }.sort

puts loaded_files
```

[image: Local Dependencies]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue was environmental and that got me looking up a line of code that was generated automatically in the `bin/console` file in my GEM.

The line `require 'bundler/setup'` which I had often seen but never understood the purpose of [Bundler Setup](https://bundler.io/guides/bundler_setup.html) provided a partial solution, but;

I found that adding `require 'bundler/setup'` only worked when I ran my exe from the same folder as the GEM but if I ran it from a different folder, it was not picking up the local dependencies.

The full solution for me only came after I read [How does rails handle gems](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-does-rails-handle-gems/) where I found out you also need to configure `ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']` to point to your GEM file.

### Code added

```rb
# This is needed to run executable from any folder
# The GemFile is relative to the project, 
# but this will force it to be absolute.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = gem_path

# Clears the $LOAD_PATH and use paths listed in project GemPath.
require 'bundler/setup'
```

### Start up executable

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'pry'

lib_path = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../lib'))
gem_path = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../Gemfile'))

$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib_path)

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = gem_path
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'k_builder/watch'

cli = KBuilder::Watch::Cli.new
cli.execute

watcher = KBuilder::Watch::Watcher.new(cli.watch_path)
watcher.start
```

### When running from GEM folder

```sh
exe/k_builder-watch ~/dev/csharp/KafeOwner/.builders
```

[image: Run from local folder]

### When running from any other folder

```sh
cd ~/dev/csharp/KafeOwner
~/dev/kgems/k_builder-watch/exe/k_builder-watch ./builders
```

[image: Run from another folder]